# Does strong typing imply type safety?

Tags: types, strong-typing

I'm reviewing lecture notes for a compilers course, and one of the slides says:

> Strongly typed languages guarantees that accepted programs are type-safe

However, I can't find any evidence of this elsewhere.

For instance wikipedia lists c++ as a language with strong typing, but also lists c as a language that isn't type safe.

So what's the deal? Are the slides wrong, or have I missed something?

[Wikipedia's example of strong typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_typing#Example)

Comment: C++ is not strongly typed. Can you please include the link where you read this?

Comment: C++ has a much stronger type system than C, though.

Comment: @ControlAltDel You are right. Later the slides defined C++ as weakly typed. Probably, wikipedia is only referring to C++ as a kind of language that would use the type-safe code in the example.

Comment: @larsmans Isn't C's type system included in C++? It seems to me that the only difference is that C++'s standard library tends to favor more type safe implementations than the C equivalents?

Comment: @larsmans the difference between c and c++ is classes / OOP. Otherwise, there's no difference in handling types

Comment: @ControlAltDel: that's not true on two accounts. The relevant one to this discussion is that C++ adds a lot of type safety beyond what is offered by C.

Comment: @bobbaluba: no, the C and C++ type systems are quite different. E.g., C++ does not implicitly promote `char` and `short` arguments to type `int`, does not implicitly convert between `void*` and other pointer types, and more generally, requires more casts; it also offers casts that perform runtime type checks. It's still possible to subvert the type system in C++, but it's (a) hardly ever needed because the language provides proper solutions to many of the problems it would solve and (b) more difficult.

Comment: @larsmans we can go back and forth about this. But fundamentally, my point is that in C & C++ data is data. There are ways in which you can get a pointer to look like anything you want it to. In Java which is strongly typed there is absolutely no way to call a JPanel a String for example

Comment: @ControlAltDel: C++ is less strongly typed than Java, that's true. But it's not a weakly typed language.

Comment: @larsmans its not Javascript, my new fav language :)

Comment: Actually, C++ also adds whole new type safety holes, e.g. through its subtyping rules that break arrays-as-pointers. I don't think there is any justification for calling C++ safer than C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Strongly typed" is not a very well-defined notion. It's probably best interpreted as synonymous to the more accurate *memory-safe* (i.e., a program can never corrupt its own memory through undefined behaviour).

In type theory, the terminology "strongly typed" is never used. Instead, one speaks of *sound* type systems. Moreover, any set of typing rules that isn't sound isn't typically regarded a proper type system at all.

In informal usage, "strongly typed" also is applied to "dynamically typed" languages, which, from a theoretical perspective, makes even less sense. In the terminology of type theory, these languages aren't even typed.

Long ago, Luca Cardelli has introduced a more coherent classification of language safety by distinguishing two independent dimensions: typed/untyped and safe/unsafe. Assembly is untyped and unsafe, C is typed but unsafe, JavaScript is untyped but safe, and Java or ML is typed and safe. See e.g. http://www.lucacardelli.name/Papers/TypeSystems.pdf